# Best practices for limited REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, caching

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I want to build an **Android** app which uses **soccer data**. I've found a service that provides soccer information via a **REST API**. The service is limited to **5,000** request/hour and I want to implement it.

If I have lots of users the app will break.

I've found a way to decrease the number of requests, by using an API-caching middleware. Example:

- https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache

Question: What are the best practices when using limited REST APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is that you implement a server-side application that caches the unique requests with a lifespan and Android application get data from it! Don't get data directly from third-parties.